# ListWheelScrollView using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, padding

Am trying to add a ListWheelScrollView to my screen but am facing a problem where it's adding a top padding

I expected the ListWheelScrollView to be paleced on top but it's as you can see in the picture below positioned at the center of the screen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcrIf.png)

```
return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: -1,
          child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
              context: context,
              removeTop: true,
              child: ListWheelScrollView(
                magnification: 2.0,
                onSelectedItemChanged: (x) {
                  setState(() {
                    selected = x;
                  });
                  print(selected);
                },
                controller: _scrollController,
                children: List.generate(
                    itemCount,
                    (x) => RotatedBox(
                        quarterTurns: 1,
                        child: AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                            width: x == selected ? 70 : 60,
                            height: x == selected ? 80 : 70,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: x == selected
                                    ? Color.fromRGBO(249, 220, 222, 1)
                                    : Colors.transparent,
                                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                            child: Text('week \n \n   $x')))),
                itemExtent: itemWidth,
              ))),
    ));
```

Comment: try removing the `Container` and see if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set up Height** for **Container** like 100,200,....

If not, Widget will spread entire screen

Don't forget remove unnessary code from your code: **MediaQuery.removePadding**